# Test whether given number is hexadecimal or not in Java?

Tags: java, exception, hex

Can someone help?

A program to test whether given number is hexadecimal or not? The number has to be input from user. If it is not hexadecimal then exception has to be thrown. the exception must be user defined.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, does it matter? The question just asks how to find out if it’s hexadecimal. “123” is hexadecimal, problem solved. :)

Comment: What's the criteria for knowing whether the number is hexadecimal? "167" is perfectly valid in both decimal and hex.

Comment: Sounds like homework, and a stupid one to be honest. 10 is hexadecimal. Its also octal, decimal and binary. So, is it hex, or not? Should the exception be thrown? How is the program going to know, what the user had in mind? A vicious teacher, and so many ways to fail this... ;-)

Comment: I expect that the OP is supposed to code this him/herself, and not rely on a library method to do all of the work.

Answer (score 5):

Use `Integer.parseInt(string, 16)`.

It throws `NumberFormatException` if `string` cannot be parsed in base-16.  If you want a user-defined exception, then catch the `NumberFormatException`, and throw your own.

Answer (score 4):

```
boolean isHex = false;
try{
    new BigInteger("ffff", 16);
    isHex = true;
}
catch(NumberFormatException ex) { }
```

You can generate an Exception with your own text like that:

```
throw new Exception("Some text");
```

Comment: @juergen ---i never seen or read about BigInteger. can you give me some info about BigInteger and proper links to study about BigInteger.

Comment: @MKod: See [here](http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/data/numbers/10biginteger.html) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively,

```
if(!text.matches("\\p{XDigit}+") {
   throw new NotHexadecimalInputException(text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

package try_catch_review;

*My own exception***

```
public class ItisNotHexDecException extends Exception{

    public ItisNotHexDecException()
    {
        System.out.println(" it is not hexa-decimal ");
    }


}
```

---

****The main program ****The above exception been used here****

```
import java.io*;

public class hexadec_orNot {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ItisNotHexDecException{

        int i;
        String s =new String();
        BufferedReader br =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println(" enter the number ");

        try{
            s=br.readLine();
            i=Integer.parseInt(s,16);
            System.out.println("entered number is hexaDecimal :   " + i);

        }  catch(NumberFormatException e)  {

            try{
            throw new ItisNotHexDecException();
            }catch(ItisNotHexDecException ee)
            {
                System.out.println("caught exception " + ee);
            }

        }  catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(" generic ");
        }
    }

}
```

@HI Oli - Your input is worth and I thank you for that. What i did you can see in above program. this is excatly what you want me to try I believe.

Adding to my original query as stated in the begininng of the this page; I need to inform you guys that A number must be accepted from user and be assigned to a string variable --I did this part and you can see in above program.

The main part of this question is "String functions" must be used to perform the processing. this is exactly what has been stated in a book I am using to learn core java.

can someone jump in and help me understand the question. I think i did right job as you guys can see the above program with my own exception.